# Python - How to get total no of style attributes of a specific div

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

How can i get total no of style attributes of a specific div

For example:

```
<div class="div1" style="direction:rtl;text-align:center;clear:both;margin:.1em;margin-bottom:1em;">
```

This div style has 5 style attributes.

```
<div class="div2" style="direction:rtl;text-align:center;clear:both;margin:.1em;">
```

This div style has 4 style attributes

Comment: Get style, split from `;`, count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

source = """
<div class="div1" style="direction:rtl;text-align:center;clear:both;margin:.1em;margin-bottom:1em;">
<div class="div2" style="direction:rtl;text-align:center;clear:both;margin:.1em;">
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    print div.get('style')
```

This will give you an output like this:

```
direction:rtl;text-align:center;clear:both;margin:.1em;margin-bottom:1em;
direction:rtl;text-align:center;clear:both;margin:.1em;
```

Now these are `str` objects. You can split them by `;` and format as you like. As for finding the number of attributes you can approach like this:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    print len(filter(None , div.get('style').split(';')))
```

Output:

```
5
4
```

Comment: You can replace `lambda x:x` in your `filter` with `None`. Quoting from docs "If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed"

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the suggestion. `lambda` function always comes first in my mind subconsciously I assume.

Answer (score 1):

Use BeautifulSoup parser.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<div class="div1" style="direction:rtl;text-align:center;clear:both;margin:.1em;margin-bottom:1em;">''', 'html')
>>> len([i for i in soup.select('.div1')[0]['style'].split(';') if i])
5
```